# Flex app not displaying images sometimes loaded from a URL

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, flash

I have the following Actionscript code in my Flex 4 app to display images on a Sprite.  Works perfect in the local flash player while developing this:

```
private function initializePhoto():void {
    var photoLoader:Loader = new Loader();
    photoLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onPhotoReady);
    photoLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://image.mydomain.com/icon/mark.png"));
}

public function onPhotoReady(event:Event):void {
    var marker:Bitmap = new Bitmap();
    marker.x = -32;
    marker.y = -8;
    marker.smoothing = true;
    marker.bitmapData = event.target.content.bitmapData;
    marker.width = 64;
    marker.height = 64;
    addChild(marker);
}
```

So I take the resulting .swf file and run it in my local webserver.  Looks good.  Upload it to staging and looks good.  The next day on staging, the image doesn't show up!  Confused, I look at firebug and it shows the image is in fact being downloaded... just not visible.  I look at firebug locally when viewing the app on my local webserver and the image is only sometimes showing up!  But always it's downloading the image.  It never fails when in dev mode through the adobe flash player.

What's going on?  I guess I'm a bit confused...  My thoughts are:

- Some kind of security issue that I didn't have before.  Would explain why it always works on the standalone adobe flash player and maybe the reason I saw the images at first was that they were cached?
- Race condition, possible?  Would explain why the adobe flash player works, because it's instant.. while the local and especially staging servers have a tiny lag.  Maybe they happened to have been particularly fast when I first tested?

My guess is there's some kind of race condition, do I have to wait after the onPhotoReady method is called before adding the Bitmap to the Sprite?

***UPDATE***: This is very frustrating to have so much trouble with such a simple operation (displaying an image from a URL).  So when this does fail, what's happening is the Event.COMPLETE event is never fired.  However, the ProgressEvent.PROGRESS is always fired twice (first with 0 bytesLoaded and then with all bytesLoaded).  No errors are ever thrown or fired.

Interestingly, when this does work, I see in Firebug that http://image.mydomain.com/crossdomain.xml is requested, while that is **not requested** when this does not work (even though ProgressEvent.PROGRESS callback shows all bytes are loaded).  I would've imagined that crossdomain.xml would be called ***before*** getting the image.

***UPDATE 2***: Fixed by simply adding the extra parameter `new LoaderContext(true)` to the `photoLoader.load()` call.

Comment: You may also need to listen for the ProgressEvent fired by the loader. I have experienced some cases before where the Complete event would sometimes not fire, and the last event that fired was a progress event with bytesLoaded matching bytesTotal (i.e. download finished).

Comment: Looks like you are correct.  For some reason the Complete event isn't firing even though all bytes are loaded...

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if this could be a cross domain policy issue??  If the issue does not happen consistently then it cannot be a security issue.

Comment: I don't know if it's a cross domain policy issue, but I load other images and they load fine from this URL... so I really doubt it.  I have not been able to duplicate getting the images to show locally and on staging..  so I'm guessing it was working before because of a cache?  hmm, but then how did it work to begin with?

Comment: . It does not appear to be cross domain policy issue. I doubt its a race condition. Flex event driven framework should be able to handle any delays. I assume that you already checked that the callback function is called.(onPhotoReady). Either the file is never loaded or the complete event is not called. Can you try to surround the loadurl call with try catch block? This will help catching any hidden exception.

Comment: Ok, so no errors thrown in any try catch blocks.  The issue is that the Event.COMPLETE callback is simply not called sometimes (most of the time).  I've confirmed this is not a cache or security problem as I have now been able to reproduce this working sometimes.  ProgressEvent.PROGRESS is called twice for each image, once with 0 bytesLoaded and again with the complete bytesLoaded.

Comment: I assume this problem is still open. If complete is not called, then an failure event should have been fired.Before understanding what event to register, could you try getting the HttpResponseStatus.urlLoader.addEventListener("httpResponseStatus", function(event:HTTPStatusEvent):void

Answer (score 0):

Incase you do not need to edit the bitmap data, you can try simply taking and image object, and giving the url as the source.
Till now that has worked for me , without fail.

Comment: How do you use Image?  I just tried var image:Image = new Image(); image.source = "http://image.mydomain.com/test.png"; addChild(image);  Unfortunately, nothing happens...

Comment: Hey, 1.please make sure that the url for the image is a valid url, i.e an image actually does exist at that url. 2.Try changing the width and height of the image object, using image.width and image.height. 3.Make sure the displayObject on which addChild is being called is already visible to the user.

Comment: all your points were satisfied, that URL was a fake URL, the real one has an image.

Comment: Im sorry to ask such trivial question but they might be necessary.Just a suggestion  , copy and paste the source url in the browser window, if you can see the image in the browser, then its a valid url.Incase not, then there is an issue with the url.The url shuold typically start with http://...